# How to fix useradd: Invalid configuration: GID_MIN (7000), GID_MAX (900)

Tags: linux, root, useradd

I am running a service as root. This service creates a user and a group but fails at creating a user with the above error

how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values are defined in `/etc/login.defs`. Obviously, `GID_MIN` being larger then `GID_MAX` doesn't make sense and you should be able to just change the values to something making more sense.

That leaves the question why the values are set to that - I would guess someone mixed things up while editing the file.

Comment: Or maybe a `0` got omitted on GID_MAX

Comment: Surely possible, yes.